# How to switch between customisation in xubuntu?

Tags: xubuntu, customization, default

Xubuntu looks boring,but is highly customisable,I want to customise it like MAC OS from a youtube tutorial.
I fear it might slow down the system to a bit.
I want a way to switch between the default system in case high performance is required (programming need)and the Customised MAC OS  look.

What Are My Options?

Comment: Just undo the changes you make. Alternatively write a script which will undo the changes. There is no other option. However, changing themes should not affect performance.

Comment: Tutorial To write a script plz

Comment: Here is a simple bash script tutorial. https://linuxhint.com/write_simple_bash_script/

Comment: Did you actually get any slowdown? I'd apply the customizations first, measure the effect, then decide if I need the switch or not.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat No I havenot tried anything yet.I dont want to break anything due to customization.I thought maybe I can configure it by using differennt users.